# iOS resize UIImageView to fit for UILabel

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UILabel with dynamic height. I am trying to place it within bubble image. How do I resize UIImageView to fit for UILabel?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set 2 constraints:

- 1 constraint to force your UIImageView to have the same **height** as the UILabel
- 1 constraint to force your UIImageView to have the same **width** as the UILabel

Additionally, you may want to add the following constraints:

- 1 constraint to align **horizontally** the center of your UIImageView with the center of your UILabel
- 1 constraint to align **vertically** the center of your UIImageView with the center of your UILabel

See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html) to learn how to add contraints programatically.

Comment: I am doing it progrmatically

Comment: Constraints can be defined programatically. I edited my answer with a link to Apple's documentation on how to achieve that.